# How to use BinaryConnection in my module to send and receive data

Tags: c#, tcp, moryx

I have a custom module `MyModule` with a custom plugin `MyPlugin` in this plugin I want to send and receive data via a BinaryConnection.
Here is a simplified version of my code

```cs
[ServerModule(ModuleName)]
public class ModuleController : ServerModuleBase<ModuleConfig> 
{
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        Container.LoadComponents<IMyPlugin>();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        Container.Resolve<IBinaryConnectionFactory>();
        Container.Resolve<IMyPlugin>().Start(); 
    }
}
```

```cs
[Plugin(LifeCycle.Singleton, typeof(IMyPlugin), Name = PluginName)]
public class MyPlugin: IMyPlugin
{
    private IBinaryConnection _connection;

    public IBinaryConnectionFactory ConnectionFactory { get; set; }

    public IBinaryConnectionConfig Config { get; set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        _connection = ConnectionFactory.Create(Config, new MyMessageValidator());
        _connection.Received += OnReceivedDoSomething;
    
        _connection.Start();
    }
}
```

When I start the Runtime I get a NullReferenceException because the `ConnectionFactory` is not injected. Where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [the binary connection](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/docs/articles/Platform/BinaryConnection.md) in your module you can either instantiate [`TcpClientConnection`](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/src/Moryx/Communication/Sockets/Client/TcpClientConnection.cs) and [`TcpListenerConnection`](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/src/Moryx/Communication/Sockets/Server/TcpListenerConnection.cs) manually or use your modules DI-Container, as you already tried and I would recommend.

To use it in your module, you need to register/load the classes into your container. Take a look at how the **Resource Management** [registers them](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-AbstractionLayer/blob/dev/src/Moryx.Resources.Management/ModuleController/ModuleController.cs#L55). In your `OnInitialize` you need:

```cs
Container.Register<IBinaryConnectionFactory>(); // Register as factory
Container.LoadComponents<IBinaryConnection>(); // Register implementations
```

Then you can add either a `BinaryConnectionConfig` entry to your config and decorate with `[PluginConfigs(typeof(IBinaryConnection), false)]` to select Socket as well as Client/Server from the MaintenanceWeb or use the derived type `TcpClientConfig`/`TcpListenerConfig` directly.

```cs
public class ModuleConfig : ConfigBase
{
    [DataMember, PluginConfigs(typeof(IBinaryConnection), false)]
    public BinaryConnectionConfig ConnectionConfig { get; set; }
}
```

In you plugin you can then inject `IBinaryConnectionFactory` and `ModuleConfig` to create the connection.

```cs
public class MyPlugin: IMyPlugin
{
    private IBinaryConnection _connection;

    public IBinaryConnectionFactory ConnectionFactory { get; set; }

    public ModuleConfig Config { get; set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        _connection = ConnectionFactory.Create(Config.ConnectionConfig, new MyMessageValidator());
        _connection.Received += OnReceivedDoSomething;
    
        _connection.Start();
    }
}
```

PS: Resolving the factory in `OnStart` returns an instance, which you don't use and is unnecessary. Don't confuse `Resolve`(Find registered implementation and create instance) with `Register`.

Comment: thanks, I guess in order to get a duplex connection I would need the `ConnectionFactory` to create two connections for me, one with the listener and one with the client config, wouldn't I?

Comment: No, the connection is always duplex. See `Send`-method and `Received`-event. Listener and Client determines whether you open a socket or connect to one. That's why they have different connection settings.